# StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document is coming when I click on button

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am following page object pattern in Protractor. In the following code I am matching the username and clicking on edit button

```
this.clickEditButton = function (userName) {        
    element.all(by.repeater('u in users')).each(function (elem) {
        elem.element(by.css('td:nth-child(1)')).getText().then(function (value) {                
            if (value == userName) {
                elem.element(by.css("a[href*='#/organisation/editUser/31']")).click();

            }
        });
    });    
};
```

The page open successfully but it is throwing " StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"

Main Method:

```
  userDirectoryPage.clickEditButton('EditUser1');            
  userEditPage.addBasicDetails('', 'Timon', 'Thompson', 'dummy1@abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'Testing');
```

Is anybody have some suggesstion how to fix this up?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are using `each()` - when the edit button is clicked, the DOM changes and the reference to the  next user element becomes "stale".

You need to use [`filter()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) instead:

```
this.clickEditButton = function (userName) {        
    element.all(by.repeater('u in users')).filter(function (elem) {
        elem.element(by.css('td:nth-child(1)')).getText().then(function (value) {                
            return value === userName;
        });
    }).first().element(by.css("a[href*='#/organisation/editUser/31']")).click();    
};
```

Comment: @ Alecxe- The solutions works for me by returning element text. Thanks a lot. You are awesome.